# How to display text in label for Line Chart (Chart) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, graph, charts, linechart

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts library for generating chart.**(Swift-iOS)**
I want to display values with **percentage values** like **1235(6%), 3478(34%), 742(3%)** and so on.

**This is what I achieved:**

[image]

**This is what I want:**

[image]

Anybody have idea then please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a something, maybe it helps you:

First you create a custom formatter:

```
class CustomVF : IValueFormatter {
var maxValue : Double = 1
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
    return "\(value) (\(value / totalSum * 100)%)"
}
}
```

Then you use it:

```
let set1 = BarChartDataSet(entries: yVals, label: "DataSet")
...
let customVF = CustomVF()
customVF.maxValue = 200.0
set1.valueFormatter = customVF
```

Comment: I don't want to calculate and set Percentage value because I already have it in my array. Any idea?

Comment: The valueformatter has just one value. How shall it know what 100% is? So you have to set this value somehow. If you set the values in the dataset anyway, why not set the maxValue in the customFormatter? Should be only 3 lines of code to do this.

Comment: I pass my array in that class, got it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

you have to define a value formatter like this example:

```
let pFormatter = NumberFormatter()
pFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
pFormatter.multiplier = 1
pFormatter.percentSymbol = " %"
data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: pFormatter))

data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: .light))
data.setValueTextColor(.white)

chartView.data = data
```

This is copied from the piechart example.

Comment: This adds % symbol after value I need to display like 1235(6%)

Comment: oh sorry, you are right. With the formatter you can only have one value...percentage or absolute.